# Why is Flask-WTF Form presenting 404 error with POST requests and not GET

Tags: post, flask, flask-wtforms

I have been looking at this for a while, trying to get this form to recognize the POST, and instead it generates a 404 error.

**Views**

```
from flask import *

from dockteck.models import EmailForm
from dockteck import app

# Page Routing 
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    form = EmailForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return "Message Sent"
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

@app.route('/portfolio')
def portfolio():
    return render_template('portfolio.html')
```

I have a simple contact function, that is working fine when a page GET is requested. The following contact page loads for a page GET:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}


<h1>Contact Me</h1>



<form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method=post>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            {{ form.name.label }}
            {{ form.name }}
        </div>

        <div class="large-4 columns">
            {{ form.email.label }}
            {{ form.email }}
        </div>

        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <div class="row collapse">
                {{ form.subject.label }}
                {{ form.subject }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            {{ form.comment.label }}
            {{ form.comment }}              
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            {{ form.submit }}
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Upon submit of this form, it returns a 404 error page, as it requests contact via POST. Additionally, with firefox dev tool inspection, it shows that the page is posting the correct page /contact, but times out with a 404 error, and gives this additional message:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The
>   document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
>   if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
>   The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or
>   in the transfer protocol.

In the template file, I have tried a few varying declarations, but it doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>               <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en" > <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
```

Let me know if I'm missing anything that would be helpful to solve this problem.

Edit: Here is EmailForm

```
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, SubmitField

class EmailForm(Form):
    name = TextField('Full Name')
    email = TextField('Email Address')
    subject = TextField('Subject')
    comment = TextAreaField('Comments')
    submit = SubmitField('Send message')
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `EmailForm`?

Comment: @JamesPorter I've appended EmailForm onto the end of my question.

Comment: hmmm weird, you're not doing anything obviously wrong and when I test it everything works fine. The only difference between what I'm doing and what you have is that I'm not extending a `template.html`, I'm just rendering what you pasted above directly. Maybe try doing that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @JamesPorter Alright, it seems that the template wasn't causing the issue on my end. Still not working after I with just one page. If it's of any help, I'm using passenger wsgi to host it, on Dreamhost hosting. It may have something to do with the setup of shared hosting.[Passenger WSGI Info](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger_WSGI)

Answer (score 0):

try to change these things :
from method=post to method="POST"
from form = EmailForm() to form = EmailForm(request.form)

and tell me if you still have any error

Comment: It's still giving me the same errors after trying out those combinations. I tested my code, and it works fine on PythonAnywhere hosting. I believe that it may have something to do with the WSGI server.